# How to get input box value without submitting form and put calculated value in other input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get two input box data without submitting form data and add them on a click of a button and show the result in another input box?

```
     _________________________
ROI:|_________________________|

            _________________________
Princilpe: |_________________________|

       _________________________
Time: |_________________________|

                  _________________________
Compound Intrest:|_________________________|
```

I want to get the values of ROI, principle amount and time duration and calculate the compound interest and show the result in rate per month input box the result will be generated only after the cal:EMI button is clicked.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F614BE7C0A8CAC5D!259&authkey=!AA9gNEG_ZrrSM8w&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Comment: Show us the _code_ you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery..like below..

you have to include first main basic jquery file 
then,

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#compoundinterest').focus(function()
    {
        var p = +$('#principal').val();
        var r = +$('#roi').val();
        var n = +$('#time').val();

        var i = ((p * r * n) / 100);

        $('#compoundinterest').val(i);

    });
});
```

here #.. shows ids of input boxes.. and '+' is used to convert string into integer..

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery or JavaScript

get value from the text field

> var variable=$('#input_field_id').val();

do the calculation with the values.

set value to the text field

> $('#result_field_id').val(calculated_value);

if You want to related with database then use Ajax